# How can i make to label return values in C#?

Tags: c#, label

So guys i am new in C# and i want to know how to make to label return some values.

One example :

- `Label1` will be 75 dollars when i click in `radiobutton`.
- When i choose the radiobutton, will change the value of 0 to 75 dollars in the painel,and will be added to the value of the buy.

I already tried some stuffs but didn't worked,i am really freaking out with this.

Please help, I need to do that for the Course of Programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Text property for set and get value from label, such as:

```
int myIntVariable1 = 934;
myLabel.Text = myIntVariable1;
int myIntVariable2 = Convert.ToInt32(myLabel.Text);
```

Now myIntVariable1 and myIntVariable2 will have 934 value

Answer (score 0):

A label cannot return a value,

if you're using a radio button \ button group, you could need to fire an CheckedChanged event, easiest way would be get the radio buttons on your form, double click for the event to get generated, then use a switch statement to have the label changed

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "your new value or text here";
}
```

Also, just as a note of interest for you and the course you're doing, sign up to PluralSight which has mass of courses, and will teach you all you need to know about the fundamentals of C# and much more.  You can get a free 10 or 14 day trial and then you can sign up from $29 per month and cancel at any time.